# Run SmallLint rule on all Classes

Tags: pharo

Given a smallint rule `RBUnclassifiedMethodsRule new`, how do I run the rule on all classes in the System?

Strangely enough `RBUnclassifiedMethodsRule new run` does not give me back the full results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give an environment to tell what are the classes to check. If you want the results of `RBUnclassifiedMethodsRule` for all the classes of the system do:

```
RBUnclassifiedMethodsRule new 
    runOnEnvironment: RBBrowserEnvironment new; 
    result
```